# Restrict Duplicate entry in a column in Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet that contains two sheets.Suppose the names are `sheet1` and `sheet2`.

There are several data in *column A* in `sheet1` and several data in *column A* in `sheet2`.

How can I restrict users when they enter data to avoid to enter duplicates of data in both sheets that is already available in *column A* `sheet1` and *column  A* `sheet2`?

That means new entries must be unique and they cannot match with anything on *column A* of `sheet1` and *column A* of `sheet2`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use "Data Validation" for that:

- go to Data - Data Validation
- In "Allow" field select "custom"
- Enter formula:
  `=(COUNTIF(Sheet1!A:A,<cell>)+COUNTIF(Sheet2!A:A,<cell>))=1`
  where `<Cell>` is the adress of the cell you're entering the validation (e.g. if whole column A is selected in Sheet1, then just enter `A1`)